# Creating radio with dynamic name in Angular for IE6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following data list in angular controller.

```
$scope.dataList = [
    {id:1, name:"Record A", action:"A"},    //action : A = Authorized
    {id:2, name:"Record B", action:"R"},    //action : R = Rejected
    {id:3, name:"Record C", action:"P"},    //action : P = Pending
    {id:4, name:"Record D", action:"A"},    
    {id:5, name:"Record E", action:"R"},    
    {id:6, name:"Record F", action:"A"} 
];
```

I have displayed data in each row with three radio buttons so user can update action value.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Pending</th>
            <th>Authorize</th>
            <th>Reject</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
            <td ng-bind="data.name"></td> 
            <td><input type="radio" name="action-{{data.id}}" ng-model="data.action" ng-value="'P'"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="action-{{data.id}}" ng-model="data.action" ng-value="'A'"></td> 
            <td><input type="radio" name="action-{{data.id}}" ng-model="data.action" ng-value="'R'"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: User Preview]

For logical grouping of radio buttons, i have used `name="action-{{data.id}}"` for separate radio button sets for each row. As `data.id` is unique for each record, so in each row, radio buttons will have same name and hence same logical group.

**It works in modern browser but, unfortunately, i have to make it work in IE6. The problem is IE6 do not allow to change the `name` attribute once radio button is created in DOM.** So `name="action-{{data.id}}"` will remain as it is resulting all radio buttons belong one logical group.

Is there any solution? I am thinking about writing a directive that generates `name` attribute before creating `radio` in DOM. Is it possible by using directive? If so, please help me.

Comment: Not related to Angular, however it is related to this IE 6 bug, I ran into this a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362513/can-i-use-javascript-to-set-the-name-attribute

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it. But can angular assign dynamic attribute value before creating the element in DOM?

Comment: Can't you just stop supporting this crap? IE 6 turned 12 this year, it need rest.

Comment: @madhead, You are right. IE is absolutely crap. But, as I said earlier, "unfortunately" I have to make things work on this it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I resolved it. (Code can be more cleaner, but this is the basic idea.)

I used a `span` with `my-radio` directive and listed other required attributes on it.

```
...
<td><span my-radio="data.id" my-model="data.action" my-value="'P'"></span></td>
<td><span my-radio="data.id" my-model="data.action" my-value="'A'"></span></td>
<td><span my-radio="data.id" my-model="data.action" my-value="'R'"></span></td>
...
```

Here is `myRadio` directive code.

```
myModule.directive('myRadio', ['$compile',function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var input = '<input type="radio" name="action-'+ scope.$eval(attrs.myRadio) +'" ng-model="' + attrs.myModel + '" ng-value="' + attrs.myValue + '">';
        element.html(input);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };  
}]);
```

This will generate following code for each row. Here `name` attribute is being generated by `"action" + data.id` expression.

```
...
<td>
    <span my-value="'P'" my-model="data.action" my-radio="data.id">
        <input type="radio" ng-value="'P'" ng-model="data.action" name="action-1">
    </span>
</td>

<td>
    <span my-value="'P'" my-model="data.action" my-radio="data.id">
        <input type="radio" ng-value="'A'" ng-model="data.action" name="action-1">
    </span>
</td>

<td>
    <span my-value="'P'" my-model="data.action" my-radio="data.id">
        <input type="radio" ng-value="'R'" ng-model="data.action" name="action-1">
    </span>
</td>
...
```

Comment: I am looking forward for any other better solution.

Comment: Since no other solution is found, I am marking this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use **{{$index}}** instead of **{{data.id}}** for **name="action-{{data.id}}"** as $index will automatically change for each element and u will have dynamic name.
Try this as alternative to using Directive,It solved Problem in my Case.