# Changing attributes values of HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know you can change almost any attribute value of an HTML elements with JavaScript. The tricky one is the name attribute. Is it possible to change with JavaScript? I have read on the internet is a readonly attribute, and you may change in some browsers but not in others. Can anyone clarify me this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a great answer on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362513/can-i-use-javascript-to-set-the-name-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
<input id="a" name="aName"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a = document.getElementById('a');
        a.name = 'newName';
        alert(a.name);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery to change the `name` attribute in the following way

```
$("selector").attr('name', 'newName');
```

or using pure javascript you can use something like:

```
document.getElementById('someId').name = 'someName';
```

or alternately you can use the `setAttribute()` function too ,but please note its not supported in IE 8 and below.

the code will be something like this

```
document.getElementById('someId').setAttribute("name","someName");
```

Name attribute is not Read-Only, you can read the specifications [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-6043025)